# webservices test on JMeter

Tags: rest, testing, jmeter

In J.meter I need to test multiple web-services in single scenario like, after successful execution of service one it will gives session-Id and this session id will take by other services and check it and complete the scenario as per business logic?

Answer (score 0):

It is classic question regarding "correlation" in JMeter. Correlation stands for the process of extracting dynamic data from previous response and passing it to the next request.

1. Add a [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the first request and define a [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query to extract the `session-Id` value and and store it into a Jmeter Variable.
2. Use the aforementioned JMeter Variable as the `session-Id` for the subsequent requests.

See [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) article for comprehensive instructions.

Comment: Can you attach Screen shoot in above procedure what you have mentioned?